# How do I replace a UITextField from storyboard to programmatically?

Tags: ios, uitextfield

I originally made an app with 5 tableviewcells where each cell had its own image and once cell had a uitextfield dropped in which contained placeholder text.  When that cell was tapped, it called a uipicker and returned the value to the uitextfield.  I wasnt using cellForRowAtIndexPath method.

I had to redo the cell's imageviews programmatically because i had to use some new behavior when the cells were tapped.  So I had to implement cellForRowAtIndexPath with a switch case to populate each cell.  I finished the cells with the UIImageViews in them but Im stumped with the cell containing the UITextField.

The uitextfield created programmatically doesnt show up.  Here is the code:

```
- (UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {


    UITableViewCell *cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:@"MyIdentifier"] autorelease];

    switch (indexPath.row) {
        case 0:
            cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Location1.jpg"];
            break;
        case 1:

            break;
        case 2:
            self.myCity = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(200,6,100,30)];
            self.myCity.text = @"Pick a city...";
            //Call UIPicker
            break;
        case 3:
            cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"driveThru1.jpg"];
            break;
        case 4:
            cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"24hrs1.jpg"];
            break;
        case 5:
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }


    return cell;
}
```

Here is the storyboard:

[image]

Here is the result:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You are setting the property myCity with your newly created UITextField. This textfield is never actually added as a subview of the cell.

Here is what I would suggest. Create a subclass of UITableViewCell and in it's initWithFrame method, create your UITextField and add it as a subview of the cell. Make sure you use unique reuseIdentifers in your cellForRowAtIndexPath for your textfield and non-textfield cells so everything is dequeued properly.

Comment: But these are 5 static cells.  I thought reuseIdentifiers were for dynamic, prototype cells?

Comment: Reuse identifiers are used to identify cells for the dequeuing process, which in your case, you aren't actually implementing currently.

Your code is using initWithStyle to create a new cell on every load. Again, the reason why your textfield isn't showing up is because you aren't adding it to the cell's subview. Try [cell addSubview:self.myCity];